# 403 Forbidden in Nginx Server

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx for the first time.  I have an index.html file in my `/home/deploy/sites/hello` directory.  I made sure the folder and index.html is owned by the user `deploy` and that the file permission is 777.

I then added this entry to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/00-app.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /home/deploy/sites/hello;
    index index.html;
    server_name hello.com;
    error_log               /var/log/nginx/tbs_error.log;
}
```

Then I did a `sudo service nginx restart`.  When I go to hello.com, I get a 403 forbidden error.  Anyone know how I might be able fix this issue?  All the other nginx sites on this server are still functioning.

Comment: Check "world"/other access (last `x` bit) capability for `/`, `/home/`, `/home/deploy/`, `/home/deploy/sites/` as well as `/home/deploy/sites/hello/`.  Also, check nginx's error log.

Comment: I just went to hello.com and it loaded just fine.

Comment: Sorry, i mean to say i had to edit my computers host file to map my own hello.com to it.  So add teh following entry `111.111.111.111 hello.com` to you hosts file in windows and replace 111.111.111.111 with your server ip address.

Comment: I might suggest you accept your own answer here - this got bumped to the homepage because its not officially correctly answered.

Answer (score 0):

As per DerfK, I noticed the `sites` directory did not have executable permission for others.  So i did chmod 757 on the sites directory and things worked

Comment: Are you sure `757` is appropriate? Would `755` work?

Answer (score 0):

Try with following commands

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data home/deploy/sites/hello* 
sudo chmod -R 0755 home/deploy/sites/hello*
```